# Ngx Charts custom chart with custom tooltip

Tags: ngx-charts

I am trying to add a custom tooltip to a custom chart in ngx charts.

I have made a double axis chart (much like [this](https://github.com/hobi4ek/double-axis-chart/blob/master/src/app/double-axis-chart/double-axis-chart.component.html) one. The chart works brilliantly.

From everything I can find on the ngx-charts docs about custom charts, I should be able to add this template inside my custom chart component

```
  <ng-template #tooltipTemplate let-model="model">
    This is the single point tooltip template
    <pre>{{ model | json }}</pre>
  </ng-template>
```

And that should show up as the tooltip on the custom chart, but I still see the normal tooltip.

There is a line in the docs stating:

> If you discover the tooltip does not display correctly, try exporting
>   the new chart as a module along with ChartCommonModule and import it
>   into the demo's app.module.ts file. 
>   For an example of this, look at most any chart in the src folder

I have tried this also, and no luck.

I have tried to figure out where the template refs are used when the custom chart views them but I cannot find how the `tooltipTemplate` is used in any of the other chart examples, after it is "viewed" like this

```
  @ContentChild('tooltipTemplate', { static: true }) tooltipTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;
  @ContentChild('seriesTooltipTemplate', { static: true }) seriesTooltipTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;
```

Any help would be much appreciated!!

Comment: any progress on this?